# Fill remaining width between elements and cut text

Tags: css, html

I have a footer to posts on a blog, the posts are of dynamic with.
There are some elements in the footer that are left-aligned, one that's right-aligned and one between them that should fill the remaining space.

I thought I could use

```
text-overflow:ellipsis
```

which works if I set it to a fix width, but at the moment, the space-filling element just gets too large so the last element breaks to a new line.

Adding

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

to the outer container didn't help.

Also it'd be a nice bonus if the space-filling element would always fill the remaining space, even if it's content is not large enough.

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MFxk5/ , the space-filling element is the

```
    <a href="c" class="c">...
```

Thanks to everyone for helping out! Maybe some will mark this as duplicate, but I think the combination with text-overflow:ellipsis makes this unique - I really searched for a solution.

Comment: To trigger the ellipsis, you need to either specify or compute a width on the `a.c` element.  Alternatively, you can use jQuery to compute the ideal width for `a.c`.  How flexible are you requirements?

Comment: I thought about using jQuery but that's a lot of load with dozens of those post-footers on one page. Apart from the ellipsis, how would I achieve to have a.c fill the remaining space by CSS only?

Comment: Would it be okay to set a % width on on the three narrow columns?

Comment: maybe, better would be a fixed width or even better a max-width...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a fixed-fluid-fixed layout here is how you do it in pure css. If its not what you mean let me know. a Fiddle to view: http://jsfiddle.net/rE2NC/ just move the viewport left and right and you will see how the middle expands contracts as the width does.

**HTML**

```
<div class="FooterContainer">
    <div class="Footer">
         <div class="Left">Left</div>
         <div class="Middle">Middle</div>
         <div class="Right">Right</div>  
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.FooterContainer {
    width:100%;
}

.Footer {
     padding-left:200px;  //or whatever width you want the .Left to be
     padding-right:200px; //or whatever width you want the .Right to be
}

.Left {
     width:200px; //Should match the padding-left of .Footer
     margin-left:-200px; //Should be the negative of the width
     float:left;
}

.Right {
     width:200px; //Should match the padding-right of .Footer
     margin-right:-200px; //Should be the negative of the width
     float:left;
}

.Middle {
     width:100%; //This fills the rest
     float:left;
     overflow:hidden; //use this to make sure text dont flow out
}
```

Comment: This works quite nicely.  It can be easily extended to have two left panels a bit like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/rE2NC/2/ and to trigger the ellipsis, the middle section needs overflow: hidden.

Comment: awesome! Made some minor adjustments for better testing on smaller screens, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you! http://jsfiddle.net/rE2NC/4/

Answer (score -1):

**jQuery Solution**

I started with a jQuery assisted solution.

The CSS looks like:

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
a {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin: 3px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
.c {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.d {
    float: right;
}
```

and the jQuery function:

```
$("div").each(function(){
    var innerWidth = 0;
    $(this).find("a").not(".flex").each(function(){
        innerWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });
    var flexWidth = $(this).width() - innerWidth - 9; /* padding + border + 1 */
    $(this).find(".flex").width(flexWidth);
});
```

There is a hard coded constant that represents the left/right padding and border on the flexible with div (`a.c` in your example), and for some reason, there is a 1px adjustment to keep the floats on a single line. (Not quite sure the origin...).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/HmvsN/

**Mix of Fixed Widths with Floats**

I made a slight adjustment to the HTML as follows (move `a.d` in front of `a.c`):

```
<div class="ex2">
    <a href="a" class="a">First column</a>
    <a href="b" class="b">Second column</a>
    <a href="d" class="d">Last column</a>
    <a href="c" class="c flex">Very long text...</a>
</div>
```

and use the following CSS:

```
.ex2 a {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin: 3px;
    height: 50px;    
}
.ex2 .a { 
    width: 90px;
    float: left;
}
.ex2 .b { 
    width: 90px;
    float: left;
}
.ex2 .c { 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
    margin: 3px 100px 3px 199px;
}
.ex2 .d { 
    width: 90px;
    float: right;
}
```

Essentially, float the left two elements and the right one such that it wraps around the wider one.  The width of the wider element has left/right margins to accommodate the floated elements.

Overall, both approaches have merit, but it seems to be a lot of work for what we are getting...